# when i call another function in faas, I get an error like 'this function not published'

Tags: node.js, express, openfaas, faas

How can i import and use faas function in another faas function in express.js?

```
const { UnsplashApi } = require('../image-api-graphql/data/unsplashApi');
```

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of this. pls look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73107911/when-ı-using-dragula-for-the-drag-and-drop-in-vuejs-project-the-target-index-is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to send request to your other function.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).